# How to escape characters in a string

Tags: javascript, escaping

Consider below response of ajax-

```
function validateVar(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"abc.do",
        datatype:"text",
        success:function(response){
            alert(response);    //"asdjakd"fsd'f'fsf"s'dfs'df"fsdf"fsfsf""
        }
    });
}
```

I want to escape all occurrences of quotes in the response.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/3w0aj5z7/

Comment: Use backslashes? Do not use `escape`, it's deprecated?

Comment: escape in what way? `encodeURIComponent` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the backslash to escape a character `\`. So to store your string in a variable we can write it like this.

```
var v = "asdjakd\"fsd\'f\'fsf\"s\'dfs\'df\"fsdf\"fsfsf";
```

Comment: I don't about the places of occurrences of the character.

Comment: Oh, the string to escape is passed via user input or something?

Comment: yes. It is actually reponse of an ajax call. check question again I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can't programmatically escape a string to make it valid JavaScript.

It has to be valid JavaScript to get through the JavaScript parser before it can be modified by JavaScript.

You have to fix it in the source code.

The `\` character starts an escape sequence in a JavaScript string literal:

```
var v = "asdjakd\"fsd'f'fsf\"s'dfs'df\"fsdf\"fsfsf";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotationmark `"` with backslash `\`

Your string should look like this:

`"asdjakd\"fsd'f'fsf\"s'dfs'df\"fsdf\"fsfsf"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use backslash to solve this
You need to add backslash for same type inverted commas(single or double).

```
function validateVar(){
   var v = "asdjakd\"fsd'f'fsf\"s'dfs'df\"fsdf\"fsfsf";
   alert(v);
}
```

Update the fiddle as well, check here :: https://jsfiddle.net/3w0aj5z7/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can include the string between `''` or `""` .
Then you must say to the variable where quotes aren't the closing ones with `\` before it.

In this case:

```
var v = ' "asdjakd"fsd\'f\'fsf"s\'dfs\'df"fsdf"fsfsf" ';
```

before ' quote

or

```
var v = " \"asdjakd\"fsd'f'fsf\"s'dfs'df\"fsdf\"fsfsf\" ";
```

before " quotes